# how to add score and loop through game

Tags: python

```
import random
x = 50
score = 0

number = random.randint(1, x)

[print("This number is divisible by ", str(i)) for i in range(1, 10) if number % i == 0]
print('The largest possible number to guess is ' + str(x))

if number < x/2:
    print('This number is less than ' + str(int(x/2)))
else:
    print('This number is larger than ' + str(int(x/2)))

print(number)

while True:
    if int(input('Guess: ')) == number:
        print('You got it')
        break
    else:
        print('Try again!')
```

What the code does so far is takes a random integer between 1 and whatever number I want. It tells me which numbers it is divisible by between 1-9 and also if it is bigger than half the maximum possible number. It essentially gives you a lot of info to guess.

I want to add a score aspect where after you guess the correct number, you will get 1 added to your score. Then it will loop back to the beginning, get a new number to guess and give all it's information again so you can guess. I'm trying to get the looping part but I'm really lost right now.

Comment: ```[print("This number is divisible by ", str(i)) for i in range(1, 10) if number % i == 0]``` will make a list full of ```None```s. And the list is completely useless

Comment: @Sujay it does actually work fine. I don't fully understand why, but I think it's because I'm not trying to print the list itself, but just using list comprehension to print "This number is divisible by..."

Comment: ```print()``` returns ```None```. In a list comprehension, when a function is called, the returned value is added to the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your guess is correct we can add 1 to your current score and print it. You can play till you guess it right. You have to put the whole code in a while loop for looping through the game after every correct answer. You can break the loop if your score is greater than 10 and the game stops.

```
import random
x = 50
score = 0

while True:
    if score >= 10:
        break

    number = random.randint(1, x)

    [print("This number is divisible by ", str(i)) for i in range(1, 10) if number % i == 0]
    print('The largest possible number to guess is ' + str(x))

    if number < x/2:
        print('This number is less than ' + str(int(x/2)))
    else:
        print('This number is larger than ' + str(int(x/2)))

    print(number)
    
    while True:
        if int(input('Guess: ')) == number:
            print('You got it')
            score+=1
            print('Your current score',score)
            break
        else:
            print('Try again!')
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation

Comment: how do i make it so after a certain amount of score, it ends?

Comment: @Sujay I explained it, is that explanation enough or should I change anything

Comment: @Abrar Habib, i have made the changes and explained it

Answer (score 0):

Haven't worked with Python myself before but I assume you want to encapsulate everything inside a huge while loop and ask at the end of each iteration if you want to keep playing

Something like this (this is more pseudocode than anything, didn't even tested it)

```
import random
x = 50
score = 0
keepPlaying = True
while keepPlaying:
    number = random.randint(1, x)
    [print("This number is divisible by ", str(i)) for i in range(1, 10) if number % i == 0]
    print('The largest possible number to guess is ' + str(x))

    if number < x/2:
        print('This number is less than ' + str(int(x/2)))
    else:
        print('This number is larger than ' + str(int(x/2)))

    print(number)

    if int(input('Guess: ')) == number:
        print('You got it')
        score++
        break
    else:
        print('Try again!')
        score--

    if (input("do want to keep playing?")=="no")
        keepPlaying = False
```

Comment: Python does not have unary increment/decrement operators (--/++).

Comment: the idea of asking to keep playing is nice, I might add it into my game. I got the rough idea now! thank you!